# Will upgrading my home connection actually give me better speeds through WebDav?

Tags: hard-drive, nas, webdav, dynamic-dns

I currently have a Synology ds411 NAS hard drive with 4x2TB hard drives in RAID 10 (so 4tb usable) and I'm about to get a job which requires a lot of travel away from home. 
I connect to the NAS over dynDNS to a 25 Down/15 Up home connection using the WebDAV protocol (and NetDrive on the Win7 laptop I use).

I'm not quite getting the speeds I want out of this NAS for listening to music and browsing through folders on it, especially when I'm 3000 miles away.

I'm thinking of upgrading my home connection to 150 Down/65 Up (cost about an extra 80 a month which is high but acceptable if it works)

My question is will this upgrade actually be worth it in terms of getting the speeds I want out of the NAS? (Assume the network I connect to with my laptop is around 40/40).

If not, Is there a better alternative to WebDAV that will allow me to see my NAS as a network hard drive from anywhere?

Comment: For those looking at this question in the future and using Win7, definitely give http://oddballupdate.com/2009/12/18/fix-slow-webdav-performance-in-windows-7/ a read. It sped up my experience quite a bit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When working remotely, you will need to inverse the upload/download numbers as that is what you will experience outside of your house. So, with a 25Mbps download speed and a 15Mbps upload speed, when working remotely, the fastest you can upload files to your server would be 25Mbps and the fastest that you can download from your server is 15Mbps.

If the network that you will be using remotely is 40Mbps down and 40Mbps up then you would see much faster speeds when trying to download/pull from your server.

You also have to remember that most internet providers use a proportional share of bandwidth. If you are uploading files to your home server and trying to download files, both speeds will be affected.

Comment: Another issue is latency.  You may get a bigger pipe, but latency will stay the same, as the laws of physics cant be bent.